# Update Selector selection with another Selector's selected value

Tags: acumatica

I have two tables: one is a header table, the second its details table. I want to implement a grid containing two selectors. The user will select a header value from the first selector which will cause the second selector to update with the related detail values. What do I need to do to get the second one to update with the proper detail values based on the first selector's selected value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set the selector to use Current and point to the Dac/Field used in your header the same way you do a view in a graph.

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<TableTwo.someOtherField,
    Where<TableTwo.someRelatedField, Equal<Current<HeaderTable.relatedField>>>))]
```

In your page file on your grid field, you need AutoRefresh set to true.

```
 <px:PXSelector ID="edAField" runat="server" DataField="AField" AutoRefresh="True" />
```

If nothing is showing in your selector, make sure the header value is committed before trying to select the value on the grid field.

Comment: For a PXSelector inside of a grid, how do I set AutoRefresh = true? I don't see the option in the Layout Editor, and when I attempt to edit the ASPX, I get the error "Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'AutoRefresh is not a valid attribute of element 'PXGridColumn'." This is my ASPX line for that specific selector: 

<px:PXGridColumn CommitChanges="True" DataField="PrimaryReasonId" Width="70" />
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="SecondaryReasonId" Width="70" <!--Refresh here -->/>
 It isn't a typical PXSelector for me because it belongs to a grid.

Comment: it doesn't go on the grid column, it goes in the RowTemplate in the PXSelector tag. Typically each column in a grid has two entries within PXGrid (one under "RowTemplate" and one under "Columns"). Look at the sales order page for example (SO301000) and search for "UOM" in the Document Details tab. It is a PXSelector with AutoRefresh="True"

Comment: I was able to get the RowTemplate created, so now I have: <RowTemplate>
         <px:PXSelector AutoRefresh="True" runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector78" DataField="PrimaryReasonId" CommitChanges="True" ></px:PXSelector>
         <px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" AutoRefresh="True" runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector79" DataField="SecondaryReasonId" ></px:PXSelector></RowTemplate>

However it is still not updating the second selector. Is it OK that the second selector is in the same DAC as the first selector, or do they need to be contained in seperate DACs?

Comment: They can be in the same DAC as the current just points to the correct Table.Field. I thought the selectors are in 2 separate tables as you mentioned a value gets set in the header (table 1), which the detail (table 2) then looks at the header value? Or is the same table/DAC used in both the header and detail?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The Header and Detail are separate tables, but I have a third table/DAC in which they will both belong as well. The user will pick a header selection, and then a detail selection which will then be stored together in this third table (along with other information). I have the third DAC set up to populate the first selector based on the Header table, then the second selector populates based on the Detail table and filtered by the current selection of the first selector. Sorry if this sounds confusing.

Comment: I think my issue has something to do with the second selector. Even when I save the entry and reload the page, SQL is never getting a request to populate the Secondary selector. If you don't mind, I'd like to use the chat feature and link my code to do on how I have the DAC set up to see if there is an issue there that you might be able to see. Let me know if you are available to do this. Thanks.

Comment: not sure how to chat in stackoverflow. Can you include the 2nd selector in the original question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144088/discussion-between-ericp-and-brendan).

Comment: Thanks Brendan! The issue ended up being a hidden pesky forgotten CacheAttached in the BLC. Once fixed, your code above did the job perfectly!